# Вывод вещественных чисел на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, float, emu8086

Когда мы работали с целыми числами мы использовали этот код чтобы вывести целое число:

```
reverse1:
    not ax
    add ax,1
    ret
printFromAX:
    push ax
    mov si,ax
    and si,800h
    cmp si,0
    jz dalee4
    call reverse2
dalee4:
    mov si,10
    mov di,0
    cloop6:
        xor dx,dx
        div si
        push dx
        inc di
        cmp ax,0
        ja cloop6
        mov cx,di
cloop7:
    pop dx
    add dl,'0'
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    loop cloop7
    pop ax
    ret
reverse2:
    push ax
    push dx
    mov dl,'-' 
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    pop dx
    pop ax
    call reverse1
    ret
mes_error:
    mov dx,offset err_msg 
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    ret

err_msg db 'Bad number entered' 
crlf db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
buffer db 6
blength db ?
bcontents:
end start
```

Помогите пожалуйста написать код для вывода вещественных чисел на ассемблере. Не разрешается использовать готовые функции.